# Mongoimport Maintain JSON array order

Tags: json, mongodb, import

I am importing a json array using mongoimport and it seems to randomly order the keys in an array.

Example:

```
{ "_id": "21178790T", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 3, "LINK_ID": 4685454, "NAME": "TEST" }}
```

may get inserted in as

```
{ "_id": "21178790T", "properties": { "LINK_ID": 4685454, "OBJECTID": 3, "NAME": "TEST" }}
```

I don't want the fields inside the array to be reordered upon importing.

Edit: technically I am using

```
[
 { "_id": "21178790T", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 3, "LINK_ID": 4685454, "NAME": "TEST" }},
 { "_id": "21178791T", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 4, "LINK_ID": 4632354, "NAME": "TEST2" }}
]
```

and then using

```
C:\MongoDB\bin\mongoimport --db dbname -c collectionname --file "input.json" --jsonArray --maintainInsertionOrder
```

Comment: You are persisting an OBJECT representation with properties there, the property ordering should not matter, nor should you assume they will always be guaranteed.  If you need a specific order, use array notation.

Comment: I cannot use array notation because I want to be able to query properties like `properties.LINK_ID =` Is there anyway to force an order for mongoimport?

Comment: If you know the keys against which you are querying, then why does order matter?

Comment: aesthetic preference by manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using an array here at all. You have JSON object not a JSON array. There is not explicit order for the properties on a JSON object. You should not expect that Mongodb will maintain the property order and you should not rely on those properties being in a particular order.

Comment: The issue is that it's really a geojson format, I will have to convert the geojson property object to a a property array.

Comment: Is there anyway to force an order for mongoimport?

Comment: There is no way to force the order of properties on an object. The order of properties on an object is never an issue. I am quite sure the geoJson format does not care what order the properties are in.

Comment: Are you actually encountering a problem or do you just have an aesthetic preference?

Comment: I think you should just tell him that object properties are not an ordered list and he will have to deal with it.

Comment: I agree whole-heartedly with comment above by @bhspencer that your manager just needs to get over this, as programmatically it makes zero difference what order the properties are in. Certainly if you want a certain presentation at the application layer you can order the properties for display purposes, but ordering them for persistence seems like you would need to add a lot of unneccessary complexity.